# Minecraft has disappeared from my x-box

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Points were bought last week for my son to download Minecraft.  He was playing quite happily this morning, but when he went to play it this afternoon, it appears to have disappeared.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Has it just disappeared off of your Xbox, or does it no longer show up on your account?

Comment: Is this for the Xbox version?

Comment: Once you've bought something on Xbox you don't need to pay again to download it again, so at the very least you ought to be able to download it fresh.

Comment: This should have been a Microsoft support question. Anyway, checking his purchase history on xbox.com should always be the first step. If the game's there, then simply redownload it. If it's not, then you should really contact Microsoft on the Xbox forums (on the same website).

Answer (score 2):

If it disappeared, try going to the market and re-installing it (do not do if it requires you to pay agian).

Also, did you check everywhere? If you did not, go into your games. Check all of those.

Comment: Yes, it might just not be on the start page of the Dashboard. You might need to pin it there to avoid going into the My Games menu every time.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before. The first time I did pay again just thinking it was deleted by accident. It happened again and here I am reading your posts and living mine. I was required to download it but no payment was requested.

Just see in the system and look for download history (purchase history ) and download it again.